# Namespace is not generated with serializing

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have this class generated from a web-service:

```
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.ServiceModel", "4.0.0.0")]
    [System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(IsWrapped=false)]
    public partial class RequestMessage {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007", Order=0)]
        public Helper.RequestType Request;

        public RequestMessage() {
        }                
    }
```

I'm trying to create an XmlDocument by:

```
var xnameSpace = new XmlSerializerNamespaces();
XmlDocument xReq = new XmlDocument();

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(RequestMessage));
            using (MemoryStream memStm = new MemoryStream())
            {
            using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(memStm))
            {                
                xnameSpace.Add("", "urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007");
                serializer.Serialize(xw, oReq, xnameSpace);
                memStm.Position = 0;
                xReq.Load(memStm);
            }
            }
```

But I'm not getting the requested namespace on the generated "xReq" XmlDocument.

What is the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` doesn't handle the `System.ServiceModel` attributes, it uses `System.Xml` attributes like `XmlElementAttribute`, `XmlRootAttribute`, etc. `System.ServiceModel` attributes are used by the `DataContractSerializer`. You can set up a webservice reference to use `XmlSerializer` attributes if you prefer that (`svcutil.exe /serializer:XmlSerializer`).